# Building a Linq Query for multiple Foreign tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have tables such as

```
Items_Authors        Pages -> Pages_Chapters -> Pages_Item

    Items_Authors          Pages         Pages_Chapters   Pages_Item
    --------------         -----------   --------------   -------------
    id                     id            id               id
    pageid  [FK]           title         Pageid [FK]      chapterid [FK]
    userid  [FK]                         title            description
```

Where each Page_ table has a `Foreign key` for the table before it.
How would I be able to tell if a `Pages_Item` belongs to a certain user if It's 3 tables away?
Would I have to Find the `Pages_Item`, then find it's Chapter then find its Page then from the page find the Authors since the `Items_Authors` has the Page ID in it?

Comment: Can you show us your domain model?

Comment: @Paul I added it to the post the tables on how it's organized.

Comment: I think you describe precisely what you need to do. There's no shortcut I can think of

Comment: @Zruty Then let me rephrase the question. Is the method I described the best way to do it? Or should I include more information in the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using entity framework, work form the page item upwards

```
bool hasUser = pageItem.PageChapter.Page.PageItemAuthors.Any(a => a.userId == userId);
```

If you want all page items where the author is a certain user then:

```
var pageItems = context.PageItems.Where(pi => pi.PageChapter.Page.PageItemAuthors.Any(a => a.userId == userId));
```

Comment: Hopefully, not sure you have tried but the above should do it.  Please upvote or accept answers you find helpful or that answer your question